# How do i make a dual y axis combination chart use the same baseline for both axis?

Tags: fusioncharts

i have combination chart with bars and lines plotted. however, i want to have their 0 values on the same line. is there an attribute that can help me achieve this goal. 
below is my chart sample xml data.

```
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><chart bgcolor="#FFFFFF" bordercolor="#CCCCCC" caption="User Evaluation Analysis" captionAlignment="left" divlinedashed="1" palette="0" pyaxisname="Criteria Weight" showValues="0" showborder="1" syaxisname="Evaluation" syaxisvaluesdecimals="2" useRoundEdges="1" xaxisname="Criteria">
<categories>
    <category label="Vehicles"/>
    <category label="Airplanes"/>
    <category label="Ships"/>
    <category label="Trains"/>
    <category label="Rocket"/>
</categories>
<dataset seriesname="User Weight Contribution">
    <set value="0.2093311962921"/>
    <set value="0.30883988679389"/>
    <set value="0.44694038419866"/>
    <set value="0.034888532715349"/>
    <set value="0.0"/>
</dataset>
<dataset parentyaxis="S" renderas="Line" seriesname="Dump">
    <set value="0.6279935888763"/>
    <set value="0.30883988679389"/>
    <set value="0.3864534993399736"/>
    <set value="-0.104665598146047"/>
    <set value="-0.0"/>
</dataset>
<dataset parentyaxis="S" renderas="Line" seriesname="A-Plus">
    <set value="-0.2093311962921"/>
    <set value="-0.30883988679389"/>
    <set value="-1.34082115259598"/>
    <set value="0.104665598146047"/>
    <set value="0.0"/>
</dataset>
<dataset parentyaxis="S" renderas="Line" seriesname="B-Minus">
    <set value="-0.2093311962921"/>
    <set value="0.9265196603816701"/>
    <set value="1.34082115259598"/>
    <set value="0.034888532715349"/>
    <set value="0.0"/>
</dataset>
<dataset parentyaxis="S" renderas="Line" seriesname="Creep">
    <set value="-0.2093311962921"/>
    <set value="-0.9265196603816701"/>
    <set value="-0.3864534993399736"/>
    <set value="-0.034888532715349"/>
    <set value="-0.0"/>
</dataset>
</chart>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the attribute "syncAxisLimits"  as 1 in the chart element.

Setting this attribute to 1 lets you synchronize the limits of both the primary and secondary axes.